# Creating SQL Server database with data and log file on synology NAS Server

Tags: sql-server, synology

I need to create a new database for an application. I planned to put the data files on NAS server (Synology 812). I tried to create the database using different paths for 2 days but nothing worked. At the bottom you can see an example path `N'\\10.1.1.5\fileserver\...`

I also tried `'N\\10.1.1.5\**volume1\fileserver**\payroll.ldf'` because from synology admin interface properties dialog shows this path for fileserver shared directory.

`fileserver` is a shared folder. I can reach that folder from file explorer.

```
\\10.1.1.5\fileserver\
```

And I can create new file or folders inside it using windows explorer. But unluckily the create statement does not work.

```
    CREATE DATABASE Payroll
    ON
    ( NAME = Payroll_dat,
       FILENAME = N'\\10.1.1.5\fileserver\payrolldat.mdf',
       SIZE = 20MB,
       MAXSIZE = 70MB,
       FILEGROWTH = 5MB )
    LOG ON
    ( NAME = 'Payroll_log',
       FILENAME = N'\\10.1.1.5\fileserver\payroll.ldf',
       SIZE = 10MB,
       MAXSIZE = 40MB,
       FILEGROWTH = 5MB )
    GO
```

I will be very happy if someone has a solution for my problem.

Thank you for your time.

Ferda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support UNC paths by default. See the KB at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304261 - *Description of support for network database files in SQL Server*.

Extracts:

> Microsoft generally recommends that you use a Storage Area Network
>   (SAN) or locally attached disk for the storage of your Microsoft SQL
>   Server database files because this configuration optimizes SQL Server
>   performance and reliability. By default, use of network database files
>   (stored on a networked server or Network Attached Storage [NAS]) is
>   not enabled for SQL Server.

It can be enabled, but you must ensure your hardware meets some strict conditions:

> However, you can configure SQL Server to store a database on a
>   networked server or NAS storage server. Servers used for this purpose
>   must meet SQL Server requirements for data write ordering and
>   write-through guarantees, which are detailed in the "More Information"
>   section.
>
> [...]
>
> Any failure by any software or hardware component to honor this protocol can result 
>   in a partial or total data loss or corruption in the event of a system failure.
>
> [...]
>
> Microsoft does not support SQL Server networked database files on NAS or networked 
>   storage servers that do not meet these write-through and write-order requirements.

Performance can also be heavily compromised:

> In its simplest form, an NAS solution uses a standard network
>   redirector software stack, standard network interface card (NIC), and
>   standard Ethernet components. The drawback of this configuration is
>   that all file I/O is processed through the network stack and is
>   subject to the bandwidth limitations of the network itself. This can
>   create performance and data reliability problems, especially in
>   programs that require extremely high levels of file I/O, such as SQL
>   Server. In some NAS configurations tested by Microsoft, the I/O
>   throughput was approximately one-third (1/3) that of a direct attached
>   storage solution on the same server. In this same configuration, the
>   CPU cost to complete an I/O through the NAS device was approximately
>   twice that of a local I/O.

So in summary, if you can't gurantee that your hardware supports these requirements, you're playing with fire. It might work for a small test environment, but I'd not host a Live database like this lest data gets corrupted or performance severely suffers.

To enable, use trace flag 1807 as decribed in the KB.

Comment: Hi Chris I have another question related to this subject can you check when you have time ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522453/create-file-stream-enabled-database-in-network-file-nas-server

Answer (score 2):

You need SQL Server 2008R2 or later. Starting with 2008R2 the UNC names are supported, although not encouraged (for all the reasons Chris mentions). An [SMB 3.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2709568) capable environment goes a long way into solving most of UNC storage problems. Prior to 2008R2 the trace flag 1807 would work, but was not a supported deployment (CSS could refuse to help you if you asked for help on *any* issue). See [SQL Server Can Run Databases from Network Shares & NAS](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/01/sql-server-databases-on-network-shares-nas/).

Comment: Hello Remus,I have already saw this page. Anyway reading that page had give me courage to plan new database on nas server :) I tried the below SQL statement at first. I didn't add all my trials to tell briefly.

Comment: I created the DB I didn't take notice on 1807 flag before.

Comment: Hi Remus I have another question related to this subject can you check when you have time ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522453/create-file-stream-enabled-database-in-network-file-nas-server

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you can do is configure a ISCSI volume in your nas device creating a RAID 5 if you have 3 or more available disk, after that you should connect your NAS and your server in an independient VLAN connected to a different network device or even in a diferent phisical network to avoid impact on your LAN due to operations traffic, in this way you will be using your NAS as a SAN

Comment: It looks like the comment, not like the  full answer